# Why does g++ not throw out of range for variable length arrays

Tags: c++, g++

I have a piece of code like so:

```
int arr[n];
int i, j, x, y;

for(y = 0; y < n; y++)
    for(x = 0; x < n; x++)
        // do stuff
// x = y = n
std::cout << arr[x][y];
```

the code is part of an implementation of A* and more surprisingly it works great, but I noticed i'm actually accessing an out of bounds element in my array. Why does g++ allow me to do this without any sort of exception being thrown?

Comment: C++ offers no array-bounds checking.

Comment: If you want bounds checking you should use a type that supports it. For example, `std:array` or `std::vector` and use the `at()` function not the `[] index operator`. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at).

Comment: well that's good to know, and scary.

Comment: @SyntacticFructose: in C++ there's a notion of only paying for what you've asked for... if you want bounds checking, `std::array`, `std::vector` etc. offer it, but by default with raw arrays the compiler trusts the programmer, allowing performance to match a C program where all checks are necessarily explicitly/manually coded.  Many other languages with "runtimes" need bounds checking for security reasons, and/or are so slow it's likely an insignificant extra overhead anyway....

Comment: You program shouldn't even be compiled, int arr[n] and then you want to access it with arr[x][y] ...?

Answer (score 1):

`std::out_of_range` is thrown by `std::vector` when accessing out of range via the `at()` member function. (and some other container checking situations).

Other out-of-range accesses just cause undefined behaviour.

`int arr[n];` is illegal in Standard C++. You are using a GNU extension which presumably also causes undefined behaviour when you go out of the bounds.

Comment: so if im placing data in an out of bounds element where does that data go? does it just go away or will it remain in that out of bound memory?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose It causes _undefined behavior_. Whatever it does is correct and there's no guarantee what it will do.